# How to filter a non-hierarchical BOM table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table 'TESTPROD' and I need to perform a query in Power BI using 'data segmentation'. When selecting an item, it should return in the table all the items that make up the Parent BOM along with their children. The table consists of three columns: **cod_Father, cod_Son, and Qty**. When selecting an item in the data segmentation, the table should first search for the item in the cod_Father column, and then the results of its cod_Son should be searched in the same table in the cod_Father column. This operation should be repeated until all cod_Son items no longer have any results in the cod_Father column.

[image]

In the image above, the searched Father code was **'EDBR140AG14451'**. Within this code, we have Son codes that are also Father codes, and so on.

How to create a Power BI query that, when a Father code is selected in the data segmentation, returns all the codes that make up the Father code in a single table?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with this data structure - it would require a recursive calculation which Powerbi does not support. You need to convert this table into a proper hierarchy first, and do it at the source (I did it using SQL in a data warehouse).

Comment: can you accept the data shows in added columns not in the previous two columns? I mean for example "STZ-01-303" as farther column been added into 3rd column with QTY.2 in 4th column and "STZ-04-294" added into 5th column with QTY.3 in 6th column?